# Excel VBA: Runtime Error 424, Object Required

Tags: vba, excel

I can't figure this issue out. I had a similar problem before, it turned out I was using a Range of a single cell, which was redundant. But in this case I need End(xlDown) and I can't get it to work. I tried a few combinations and I can't figure out the right syntax. Help?

```
Public Exceptions As Range
Public Xcept As Range

Sub Example()
Static ExcSh As Worksheet
Set ExcSh = Worksheets("ComboExceptions")
Set Exceptions = ExcSh.Range("A2")

Set Xcept = ExcSh.Range(Exceptions.Offset(1).Cells, Exceptions.Offset(1).Cells.End(xlDown))
'This is where the error happens ^
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the two instances of `.Cells`

Comment: Is there a reason you just didn't start in A3 instead of A2 then `.Offset(1)` ?

Comment: There is, a very good reason yes. Either way, I solved it. Will post an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! I had declared

```
Static ExcSh As Worksheet
```

in another Sub making it inaccessible to the function that errored. I made it public and now the following command works fine:

```
Set Xcept = ExcSh.Range(Exceptions.Offset(1), Exceptions.Offset(1).End(xlDown))
```

Comment: As per @Jeeped comment above `Set Xcept = ExcSh.Range(Exceptions, Exceptions.End(xlDown))` would also suffice if you adapt your starting point.